# Eclipse compiled files are not runnable by java command

Tags: java, eclipse

When you write a simple Java Application in Eclipse in automatically compiles those files and stores them in the bin/ folder of the root folder of the project.

Now if I navigate to the /bin folder and to the folder that contains the .class file I want to run via the java command below I am getting the following error - :

> java A
>   Error: Could not find or load main class A

Class A:

```
package assurance;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

While the class A has a main method and runs fine when I right click on the file and do a Run As Java Application. But it does not run from the command like java command.

Why is this happening ?

Update:

Tried with the following commands-:

```
java -cp "A.class" assurance.A
java -cp "A" assurance.A
java -cp "*" assurance.A
```

Comment: I think you missed the package name. It should be `java assurance.A` with the .class file being in the classpath.

Comment: I just tried with the command `java assurance.A -cp A.class`. Still the same error.

Comment: Are you trying to run this command through the command line?

Comment: @Aaron yes I am trying to to the folder open a cmd prompt and testing if I run the `.class` file

Comment: @ng.newbie class name should be last argument. 
try this: `java -cp ./ assurance.A` from "default package" directory.

Comment: @MikhailBoyarsky No. Same error. I just want to know how eclipse is able to run the file when I am not able to start it from the command line ?

Comment: @ng.newbie because eclipse just runs it with correct -cp and correct command :)
My solution should work, I double checked it now. Maybe some odd cmd rule breaks in, it's worth trying `java -cp "./" assurance.A` (Windows XP may have such issue). Try to run cmd from the directory that contains assurance/ directory (one level higher than you say you do in question).

Comment: @MikhailBoyarsky Yep it works. Can you please explain why it does not work from within the directory ? Why do I have to go one level up. Plus please convert the comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in Eclipse, because Eclipse just runs it with correct -cp and correct command :)

Run your code with the following command:
`java -cp "./" assurance.A` (`""` for some odd cmd interpreters like Windows XP)
it is important that the command is run from the "default package" directory (top-level package directory).

Java interprets package name (`assurance`) as directory path to the class file. Imagine if it replaces `.` with `/` and adds `.class` extension 
(`assurance.A` => `./assurance/A.class`)

More details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html